# CORS + AXIOS+REACTJS

Tags: javascript, http, axios

Пишу клиента, используя ReactJS, для http запросов использую axios, делаю пост запрос к серверу, на сервере запрос обрабатывается и возвращает данные и код 200, но в браузере ошибка:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://Xxxxxx' from origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

и предупреждение

> xhr.js:166 Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin
>   response
>   'https://Xxxxxx'
>   with MIME type application/json. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more
>   details.

Почитал что было предложен браузером но не помогло

Код:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const baseIP = ''

const baseURL = 'x' + baseIP

const baseAPI = axios.create({
    baseURL: baseURL,
});

const getConfig = (params) => {
    return {
        baseURL: baseURL,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        params: params,
    };
};


const API = {
    // isAuth: () => { return Auth.isAuthenticated(); },
    // Login: (data, handler) => { return Auth.authenticate(data, handler); },
    // Logout: (handler) => { return Auth.signout(handler); },
    GET: (path, params) => baseAPI.get(path, getConfig(params)),
    POST: (path, data) => baseAPI.post(path, data, getConfig()),
    PUT: (path, data) => baseAPI.put(path, data, getConfig()),
    DELETE: (path, params) => baseAPI.delete(path, getConfig(params)),
};

class BotService{
    getFonds = () => API.POST('x')
};

export default BotService;
```

Можете подсказать куда копать?

Comment: Ну таки в тексте ошибки написано, каких заголовков не хватает в ответе сервера, чтобы оно заработало. Если сервер не ваш - придётся проксировать запросы через ваш сервер.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это решается двумя способами.

- Использовать callback в запросе jsonp.
- Или на сервере api добавить
  заголовок  Access-Control-Allow-Origin с доменом, с которого
  выполняется запрос.

Как третье решение - проксировать запросы апи на сервере исключив при этом CORS.

Comment: У меня такая же проблема, однако браузер отлично получает ответ от сервера, а axios выдаёт ошибку. Значит проблема не в сервере.

Comment: @РамазанАлисханов ответ браузер получает в любом случае. А вот если есть хидер корс, то передает в жс, если нет хидера - блокирует

Comment: Я поставил следующий хэдэр:
headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
            }

Не работает

Comment: @РамазанАлисханов тогда у вас другая проблема)